# In Android, how may I convert dimension value to exact floating point value?

Tags: android

I have a dimension resource value as

```
<dimen name="arrowButton_textValue_textSize">20sp</dimen>
```

I use that value in two following ways

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/arrowButton_textValue"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="@dimen/arrowButton_textValue_textSize"/>
```

and

```
float _textSize = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.arrowButton_textValue_textSize);
TextView _textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.arrowButton_textValue);
_textView.setTextSize(_textSize);
```

I thought those two methods are identical though they cause different text size on real devices. For instance on some devices (HTC Wildfire S) they look the same but on HTC Desire they aren't and the second method generates bigger text size

How may I convert a dimension to exact floating point on real device based on device actual display metrics?

Comment: What is the font size setting on each device?

Comment: font size on both devices is device default font size (settings). I mean they have not been changed

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784353/inconsistency-when-setting-textview-font-size-in-code-and-in-resources)