# Android Textview text size is different as set by XML and Java

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-xml

I get different text sizes when I set text size of a **TextView** by layout **XML** and **Java** code. My layout looks like the following.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Some text"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>
```

And I tried setting text size in Java by following two ways.

**Option 1**

```
TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
titleView.setTextSize(18 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
```

**Option 2**

```
TextView titleView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
titleView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
```

The text size set by Java code (both option 1 and 2) appears **much bigger** than the text size set by layout XML. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784353/inconsistency-when-setting-textview-font-size-in-code-and-in-resources

Comment: Please do not discourage people from asking questions by down-voting it within 5 mins of submit. I took some time searching it and some more time writing that question. There is always chance that I don't find the exact post on stackoverflow that I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to reduce the size by screen density

```
titleView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, (18 / getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
```

Comment: Thanks. Also found out that using `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX` instead of `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP` gives correct text size.